# Restoring /root file system in debian Linux!

Tags: linux, backup, restore

How can i restore Linux system if its /root file system is corrupted?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "/root file system is corrupted" ? Some error message perhaps would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to boot from a Live Distro like Knoppix, and run fsck

Comment: It's spelled `fsck`.

Comment: A downvote for a typo? ROTFL, you are someone

Comment: tough crowd. +1 for fixing said typo.

Comment: +1 because you are right !